# WPF binding with no duplicates

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a collection of objects that look like this:

```
List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();
objects.Add(new MyObject("Stapler", "Office"));
objects.Add(new MyObject("Pen", "Office"));
objects.Add(new MyObject("Mouse", "Computer"));
objects.Add(new MyObject("Keyboard", "Computer"));
objects.Add(new MyObject("CPU", "Computer"));

class MyObject{

    public string name;
    public string category;

    public MyObject(string n, string c){
    name=n;
    category=c;
    }

}
```

Can I bind that collection to a List in WPF, and have it display the categories of the objects (without duplicates)? (maybe along with the count of objects that's in that category)

For example, i would like the list to show only two items, "Office" and "Computer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CollectionViewSource` with a `PropertyGroupDescription`.

In your `Resources`, add the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=CollectionPropertyOnViewModel}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Category"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then, for your `ItemsControl`, set the `ItemsSource` to `{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollectionViewSource}}`.

To style the header template, set the `ItemsControl.GroupStyle` property. Also create a `DataTemplate` for the items.

Read an excellent blog post from Bea Stollnitz [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=17).

Comment: A lot of people are answering the question with `LINQ`. I feel that they did not even read your question and just read that you wanted no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with LINQ, e.g.:

```
public class AggregateCount
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public AggregateCount(string name, int count)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Count = count;
    }
}

var aggregateCounts = objects.GroupBy(o => o.category).Select(g => new AggregateCount(g.Key, g.Count()));
ObservableCollection<AggregateCount> categoryCounts = new ObservableCollection<AggregateCount>(aggregateCounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever yuo want, that is the beauty of WPF.

Make a query to recover *what you want* in *format you want* in **ModelView** layer and bind the result to **View**. Try to make most complicated stuff of yuor programm on **Model** layer and leave "dummy" stuff to final binding, as much as it possible obviously, cause the Model and ModelView stuff will be easier to *debug* and *fix errors* in the *future*.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Linq :

```
List<MyObject> distinctObj = (from o in objects select o).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use Linq:

```
private List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();
public ObservableCollection<String> Groups
{
  get
  {  
     ObservableCollection<String> temp = new ObservableCollection<String>();
     foreach (MyObject mo in objects)
     {
       if (!temp.Contains(mo.category))
         temp.Add(mo.category)
     }
     return temp;
  }
  set
  {
     objects = value;
     RaisePropertyChanged("Groups");
  }
}
```